# Adding via ajax one to one related data .net Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have 2 tables, one is a one to one or one to zero relationship:

```
 public class ComponentText
    {
        [Key]
        public int ComponentTextId { get; set; }
        public string ComponentContent { get; set; }
        public ComponentTextSection ComponentTextSection { get; set; }
    }

public class ComponentTextSection
    {
        [Key]
        public int ComponentTextId { get; set; }
        public string SectionTitle { get; set; }
        public ComponentText ComponentText { get; set; }
    }
```

I can add row fine using usual .net core posting using a form, here is code which does this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

           var newComponentText = new ComponentText();

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ComponentText>(
            newComponentText,
           "ComponentText",
             i => i.ComponentTextSection, i => i.ComponentContent))
            {
                _context.ComponentText.Add(newComponentText);
              await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

           }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

I need to update though via ajax, but I am having issues updating the SectionTitle using this current way. It adds the data to the ComponentText table fine but not the ComponentTextSection table. Here is my ajax code:

```
  function saveWindow() {


var ComponentText = { "ComponentText.ComponentTextSection.SectionTitle": $("#ComponentText_ComponentTextSection_SectionTitle").val(), 
"ComponentTextId": $("#ComponentText_ComponentTextId").val(),
"ComponentContent": $("#ComponentText_ComponentContent").val()};

                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@AntiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken'
        },
                     data: JSON.stringify(ComponentText),
        url: '@Url.Page("Edit", "demo4")',
        success: function (result) {
            closeWindow();
        }
        });


        }
```

It must be to do with ComponentText.ComponentTextSection.SectionTitle but I have been trying lots of things to get this to work but failing. Does anyone know how to pass a one to one related data via ajax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the one-to-one model, if you want to use ajax to transfer the complex nested model to the page, you need to create **the same as the ComponentText model structure** in saveWindow function of `ComponentText variable`.

```
  <script>
        function saveWindow() {
            var ComponentText = {
                "ComponentTextSection":
                 {
                    "SectionTitle": $("#ComponentText_ComponentTextSection_SectionTitle").val(),
                 },
                "ComponentTextId": 1,
                "ComponentContent": $("#ComponentText_ComponentContent").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
               type: 'PUT',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                headers: {
                  'RequestVerificationToken':
                      '@AntiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken'
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(ComponentText),
                url: '@Url.Page("Edit", "demo4")',
                success: function (result) {
                    closeWindow();
                }
            });


        }
    </script>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]